# How to assign date as LocalDate in Angular Typescript

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, localdate

I am trying to make angular page and using typescript for it and i am using mat date picker for selecting date, backend method is waiting a parameter as LocalDate

```
sendStartDateChangeEmail(updateData: { employeeId: number, selectedDate: string }) {
    const requestParams = new HttpParams().append('requestedStartDate', updateData.selectedDate);
    return this._http.post(`/request-start-date-change/` + updateData.employeeId, null, {params: requestParams})
      .map((response: any) => {
      if (response['success'] !== true) {
        throw Observable.throw(response['errorMessage']);
      }
      return response;
    });
  }
```

as you see above updateData.selectedDate is a string, in backend method is accepting date as LocalDate not string.

```
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> sendStartDateChangeRequest(@PathVariable(name = "employeeId") long employeeId,
                                                           @RequestParam(name = "requestedStartDate") LocalDate requestedStartDate)
```

How can i assign variable as LocalDate in front end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript date to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233882/javascript-date-to-java-time-localdate)

Comment: JSON doesn't support dates, they become strings. Your backend is responsible for understanding dates, represented as strings, and deserializing them properly.